# subprogress Popen is hung

Tags: python

```js
def hello():
    while True:
     print 'subprocess = ' + str(os.getpid())
     time.sleep(1)
def killPid(pid):
 print 'kill ' + str(pid)
 os.system("taskkill" + ' /T /F /pid '+ str(pid))

p = subprocess.Popen(hello())
# p = subprocess.Popen("ping 10.193.101.34", shell=True)
print 'after subprocess'
t = threading.Timer(3.0, killPid, args=(p.pid,))
t.start()  # after 3 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

while the popen is hung?
the subprogress is not killed

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` is not even executed. It's clear, since 'after subprocess` is not printed in your console. `hello()` never completes, so input arguments for `Popen` are never evaluated. All input arguments have to be evaluated before call. Popen is used to run _external_ binaries. You seems to want to run python code in non-blocking fashion. Are you looking for [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)?

Comment: I want to use popen to excute the function hello() as a process

Answer (score 2):

It seams that you want to execute the function hello() as a process. To do so you can try to call Popen with something like

```
["python","-m",__file__,"-c","hello()"]
```

to run a new instance of the python interpreter that executes your hello function.

Comment: could it use popen to excute the function hello() as a process in one instance of the python?

Comment: You may not be able to do it as Popen is used to create a subproces